# How can I do a scikit-learn grid search with training data that is an iterator

Tags: python, iterator, scikit-learn

I am working on a text classification problem, using a pipeline that looks like this:

```
self.full_classifier = Pipeline([
        ('vectorize', CountVectorizer()),
        ('tf-idf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('classifier', SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight='balanced'))
    ])
```

The full corpus is too large to fit in memory, but small enough that after the vectorization step I have no memory issues. I can successfully fit a classifier by using

```
self.full_classifier.fit(
        self._all_data (max_samples=train_data_length),
        self.dataset.head(train_data_length)['target'].values
)
```

where self._all_data is an iterator that yields the documents per training example (while self.dataset just includes document id's and targets). Here, max_samples is optional, I am using it to do a split on training/testing data. I now want to use gridsearch to optimize parameters, for which I am using this code:

```
parameters = {
        'vectorize__stop_words': (None, 'english'),
        'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
        'classifier__class_weight': (None, 'balanced')
    }
gridsearch_classifier = GridSearchCV(self.full_classifier, parameters, n_jobs=-1)
gridsearch_classifier.fit(self._all_data(), self.dataset['target'].values)
```

My problem is that this generates the following error:

```
TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <type 'generator'>
```

with the traceback pointing at the gridsearch_classifier.fit method (and then into scikit's code, error raised in _num_samples(x). Since it is possible to fit with a generator as input, I was wondering if there is also a way to do this with the grid search, that I am currently missing.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without materializing the generator as a list. While various fit methods can often be structured to consume one item at a time, and thus accept an iterator, grid search additionally performs cross-validation and generates cv splits of the data by indexing a realized set.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'll look into faking a list by implementing a __getitem__ that hits the database